# Pandas Issue with foreign letters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am having an issue with a pandas dataframe that has foreign characters in it. It is a dataset of NBA players and some of the foreign players have names with accents and such, e.g. Kristaps Porziņģis. On any dataframe that has a player with foreign letters in their name I cannot set the value of any of the rows of the dataframe without it returning all NaN for that row.

For Example when I run:

```
dal_2018 = all_dict['2018-2019']['DAL'] 
dal_2018.loc[dal_2018['Player'] == 'Kristaps Porziņģis
```

I get the following output: 
[image]

And when I run:

```
dal_2017 = all_dict['2017-2018']['DAL']
dal_2017.loc[dal_2017['Player'] == 'Kristaps Porziņģis']
```

the output I get is: [image]

This all makes sense, but when I try to fill the original row with the stats from the second row by doing:

```
dal_2018.loc[dal_2018['Player'] == 'Kristaps Porziņģis'] = dal_2017.loc[dal_2017['Player'] == 'Kristaps Porziņģis']
dal_2018
```

The following is output: 
[image]

Where the all NaN row was the row originally filled with Kristaps Name and Position with all NaN for stats.

I have used the same line of code to fill in rows with missing values for other players with no issues. However if the dataframe contains a player with foreign characters in their name, whenever I try to do an assignment similar to above (whether on a foreign player or not) I just get a row full of NaN values.

Does anyone know what is causing this/what a fix would be?

Comment: does this work? `dal_2018.loc[dal_2018['Player'] == 'Kristaps Porziņģis'] = dal_2017.loc[dal_2017['Player'] == 'Kristaps Porziņģis'].values` ?

Comment: @anky_91 it does! thanks a lot. Do you happen to know why this works whereas if I don't include .values it doesn't?

Comment: since the matching rows in both the dataframes shares different index, you have to acces the underlying numpy array while assigining